# R: split on one column, apply function on each group and display all columns from each group in the output

Tags: r, split, plyr, lapply

I have a data set like this:`

```
  > data
   seq desc  id      sample1 sample2 sample3
1 atgc  pqr 123 1.000000e+00       1       1
2 atgc  pqr 123 2.000000e+00       2       2
3  atg   pq  12 1.000000e+00       1       1
4 atgc  pqr 123 3.000000e+00       3       3
5  atg   pq  12 2.000000e+00       2       2
6  atg   pq  12 7.757019e-05       3       3
7  atg   pq  12 1.402031e-05       3       3
```

I want to split the data on 'seq' column and calculate median of all columns in each group. I want to display columns desc,id as well in the output. The output should be something like this:

```
seq desc  id   sample1 sample2 sample3
1  atg   pq  12 0.5000388     2.5     2.5
2 atgc  pqr 123 2.0000000     2.0     2.0
```

I have tried using split&lapply combination and the result is,

```
lapply(split_data,function(x)apply(x[,c(4,5,6)],2,median))
$atg
  sample1   sample2   sample3 
0.5000388 2.5000000 2.5000000 

$atgc
sample1 sample2 sample3 
      2       2       2
```

With ddply,

```
ddply(data,.(seq),function(x)apply(x[,c(4,5,6)],2,median))
   seq   sample1 sample2 sample3
1  atg 0.5000388     2.5     2.5
2 atgc 2.0000000     2.0     2.0
```

Is there a way to include desc,id columns from each group to the final data frame to get the output as mentioned above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ddply` you can use `colwise`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(seq, desc, id), colwise(median))
#    seq desc  id   sample1 sample2 sample3
#1  atg   pq  12 0.5000388     2.5     2.5
#2 atgc  pqr 123 2.0000000     2.0     2.0
```

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~seq+desc+id, data, median)
#   seq desc  id   sample1 sample2 sample3
#1  atg   pq  12 0.5000388     2.5     2.5
#2 atgc  pqr 123 2.0000000     2.0     2.0
```

A similar option with `data.table` first needs the 'class' of the 'sample' columns to be similar as the expected output

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, 4:6 := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=4:6][,
                            lapply(.SD, median), .(seq, desc, id)]
#    seq desc  id   sample1 sample2 sample3
#1: atgc  pqr 123 2.0000000     2.0     2.0
#2:  atg   pq  12 0.5000388     2.5     2.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `desc` and `id` don't vary within group, you can do the following with `dplyr`

```
data %>% 
    group_by(seq, id, desc) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(median))
```